# Page prevented back/forward cache restoration problem

Tags: html, css, lighthouse

as i mentioned above I have problem with cache restoration while testing in lighthouse. It shows me that the problem is in my index.html file but I cant find it also i tried to find reason in internet but i couldnt fint satisfying answer. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTrp2.jpg) I will be happy for explanation.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Omnifood is an AI-powered food subscription that will make you eat healthy again, 365 days per year. It's tailored to your personal tastes and nutritional needs."
    />

    <!-- Always include this line of code!!! -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="img/favicon — kopia.png" />
    <link rel="icon-apple-touch" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/queries.css" />

    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>

    <title>Omnifood</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="logo" src="img/omnifood-logo.png" alt="omnifood logo" />
      </a>
      <nav class="nav-main">
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#how">How it works</a>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#meals">Meals</a>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
        <a class="main-nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
        <a class="main-nav-link nav-cta" href="#cta">Try for free</a>
      </nav>
      <button class="nav-button">
        <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="hero-section">
        <div class="hero">
          <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1 class="primary-heading">
              A healthy meal delivered to your door, every single day
            </h1>
            <p class="hero-text">
              The smart 365-days-per-year food subscription that will make you
              eat healthy again. Tailored to your personal tastes and
              nutritional needs. We have delivered 250,000+ meals last year!
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-full margin-right" href="#cta"
              >Start eating well</a
            >
            <a class="btn more" href="#how">Learn more &darr;</a>
            <div class="delivered-box">
              <div class="delivered-meals">
                <div class="delivered-imgs">
                  <img
                    src="img/customers/customer-1.jpg"
                    alt="customer image"
                  />
                  <img
                    src="img/customers/customer-2.jpg"
                    alt="customer image"
                  />
                  <img
                    src="img/customers/customer-3.jpg"
                    alt="customer image"
                  />
                  <img
                    src="img/customers/customer-4.jpg"
                    alt="customer image"
                  />
                  <img
                    src="img/customers/customer-5.jpg"
                    alt="customer image"
                  />
                  <img
                    src="img/customers/customer-6.jpg"
                    alt="customer image"
                  />
                </div>
                <p class="delivered-text">
                  <span class="delivered-number">250,000+</span> meals delivered
                  last year!
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hero-img-box">
            <picture>
              <source srcset="img/hero.webp" type="image/webp" />
              <source srcset="img/hero.oxi.png" type="image/webp" />

              <img
                class="hero-img"
                src="img/hero.oxi.png"
                alt="Eating woman and some dishes"
              />
            </picture>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section-feature-in">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="heading-featured-in">As featured in</h2>
          <div class="feature-imgs">
            <img src="img/logos/techcrunch.png" alt="techcrunch logo" />
            <img
              src="img/logos/business-insider.png"
              alt="business-insider logo"
            />
            <img
              src="img/logos/the-new-york-times.png"
              alt="the new york times logo"
            />
            <img src="img/logos/forbes.png" alt="forbes logo" />
            <img src="img/logos/usa-today.png" alt="usa-today logo" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section-how-to" id="how">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="subheading">How it works</span>
          <h2 class="secondary-heading">
            Your daily dose of health in 3 simple steps
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container grid grid--2col">
          <div class="how-to-text-box">
            <p class="step-number">01</p>
            <h3 class="tertiary-heading">
              Tell us what you like (and what not)
            </h3>
            <p class="how-to-description">
              Never again waste time thinking about what to eat! Omnifood AI
              will create a 100% personalized weekly meal plan just for you. It
              makes sure you get all the nutrients and vitamins you need, no
              matter what diet you follow!
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="how-to-img-box">
            <img
              class="step-img"
              src="img/app/app-screen-1.png"
              alt="app image"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="how-to-img-box">
            <img
              class="step-img"
              src="img/app/app-screen-2.png"
              alt="app image"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="how-to-text-box">
            <p class="step-number">02</p>
            <h3 class="tertiary-heading">Approve your weekly meal plan</h3>
            <p class="how-to-description">
              Once per week, approve the meal plan generated for you by Omnifood
              AI. You can change ingredients, swap entire meals, or even add
              your own recipes.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="how-to-text-box">
            <p class="step-number">03</p>
            <h3 class="tertiary-heading">Receive meals at convenient time</h3>
            <p class="how-to-description">
              Best chefs in town will cook your selected meal every day, and we
              will deliver it to your door whenever works best for you. You can
              change delivery schedule and address daily!
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="how-to-img-box">
            <img
              class="step-img"
              src="img/app/app-screen-3.png"
              alt="app image"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section-meals" id="meals">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <span class="subheading">Meals</span>
          <h2 class="secondary-heading">
            Omnifood AI chooses from 5,000+ recipes
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container grid grid--3col margin-bottom-md">
          <div class="meal">
            <img class="meal-img" src="img/meals/meal-1.jpg" alt="meal image" />
            <div class="meal-content">
              <span class="tag tag-vegetarian">Vegetarian</span>
              <p class="meal-title">Japanese Gyozas</p>
              <ul class="atributes-list">
                <li>
                  <ion-icon
                    class="icon-atribute"
                    name="flame-outline"
                  ></ion-icon>
                  <span> <strong>650</strong> calories </span>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <ion-icon
                    class="icon-atribute"
                    name="restaurant-outline"
                  ></ion-icon>
                  <span>
                    NutriScore
                    <strong>74</strong>
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <ion-icon
                    class="icon-atribute"
                    name="star-outline"
                  ></ion-icon>
                  <span> <strong>4.9</strong> rating (537) </span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="meal">
            <img class="meal-img" src="img/meals/meal-2.jpg" alt="meal image" />
            <div class="meal-content">
              <span class="tag tag-vegan">Vegan</span>
              <span class="tag tag-paleo">Paleo</span>
              <p class="meal-title">Avocado salad</p>
              <ul class="atributes-list">
                <li>
                  <ion-icon
                    class="icon-atribute"
                    name="flame-outline"
                  ></ion-icon>
                  <span> <strong>400</strong> calories </span>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <ion-icon
                    class="icon-atribute"
                    name="restaurant-outline"
                  ></ion-icon>
                  <span>
                    NutriScore
                    <strong>92</strong>
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <ion-icon
                    class="icon-atribute"
                    name="star-outline"
                  ></ion-icon>
                  <span> <strong>4.8</strong> rating (441) </span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="meals-options">
            <h3 class="tertiary-heading">Works with any diet</h3>
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon
                  class="icon-meals"
                  name="checkmark-outline"
                ></ion-icon>
                <span>Vegetarian</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Vegan</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Pescatarian</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Gluten-free</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Lactose-free</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Keto</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Paleo</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Low FODMAP</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Kid-friendly</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container text-center">
          <a class="link" href="#">See all recipes &rarr; </a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section-testimonial" id="testimonials">
        <div class="testimonials-content">
          <span class="subheading">Testimonials</span>
          <h2 class="secondary-heading">Once you try it, you can't go back</h2>
          <div class="testimonials">
            <figure class="testimonial">
              <img
                class="testimonial-img"
                src="img/customers/dave.jpg"
                alt="image of Dave"
              />
              <blockquote class="testimonial-text">
                Inexpensive, healthy and great-tasting meals, without even
                having to order manually! It feels truly magical.
              </blockquote>
              <p class="testimonial-name">&mdash;Dave Bryson</p>
            </figure>

            <figure class="testimonial">
              <img
                class="testimonial-img"
                src="img/customers/ben.jpg"
                alt="image of Ben"
              />
              <blockquote class="testimonial-text">
                The AI algorithm is crazy good, it chooses the right meals for
                me every time. It's amazing not to worry about food anymore!
              </blockquote>
              <p class="testimonial-name">&mdash;Ben Hadlay</p>
            </figure>

            <figure class="testimonial">
              <img
                class="testimonial-img"
                src="img/customers/steve.jpg"
                alt="image of Steve"
              />
              <blockquote class="testimonial-text">
                Omnifood is a life saver! I just started a company, so there's
                no time for cooking. I couldn't live without my daily meals now!
              </blockquote>
              <p class="testimonial-name">&mdash;Steve Miller</p>
            </figure>

            <figure class="testimonial">
              <img
                class="testimonial-img"
                src="img/customers/hannah.jpg"
                alt="image of Hannah"
              />
              <blockquote class="testimonial-text">
                I got Omnifood for the whole family, and it frees up so much
                time! Plus, everything is organic and vegan and without plastic.
              </blockquote>
              <p class="testimonial-name">&mdash;Hannah Smith</p>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-1.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-2.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-3.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-4.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-5.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-6.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-7.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-8.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-9.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-10.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-11.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
          <figure class="gallery-item">
            <img
              src="img/gallery/gallery-12.jpg"
              alt="beautifuly arranged food"
            />
          </figure>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section-pricing" id="pricing">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="subheading">Pricing</span>
          <h2 class="secondary-heading">
            Eting well without breaking the bank
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="container grid grid--2col margin-bottom-md">
          <div class="pricing-plan starter">
            <div class="plan-header">
              <p class="plan-name">plan</p>
              <p class="pricing">
                <span>$</span>
                399
              </p>
              <p class="plan-text">per month. That's just $13 per meal!</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>1 meal per day</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Order from 11am to 9pm</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Delivery is free</span>
              </li>

              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
                <span></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="plan-sing-up">
              <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Start eating well</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pricing-plan complete">
            <div class="plan-header">
              <p class="plan-name">plan</p>
              <p class="pricing">
                <span>$</span>
                649
              </p>
              <p class="plan-text">per month. That's just $11 per meal!</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list">
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>2 meal per day</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Order 24/7</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Delivery is free</span>
              </li>

              <li class="list-item">
                <ion-icon class="icon-meals" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon
                ><span>Get access to latest recipes</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="plan-sing-up">
              <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Start eating well</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container grid">
          <aside class="plan-details">
            Prices include all applicable taxes. You can cancel at any time.
            Both plans include the following:
          </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="container grid grid--4col">
          <div class="feature">
            <ion-icon class="feature-icon" name="infinite-outline"></ion-icon>
            <p class="feature-title">Never cook again!</p>
            <p class="feature-text">
              Our subscriptions cover 365 days per year, even including major
              holidays.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature">
            <ion-icon class="feature-icon" name="nutrition-outline"></ion-icon>
            <p class="feature-title">Local and organic</p>
            <p class="feature-text">
              Our cooks only use local, fresh, and organic products to prepare
              your meals.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature">
            <ion-icon class="feature-icon" name="leaf-outline"></ion-icon>
            <p class="feature-title">No waste</p>
            <p class="feature-text">
              All our partners only use reusable containers to package all your
              meals.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="feature">
            <ion-icon class="feature-icon" name="pause-outline"></ion-icon>
            <p class="feature-title">Pause anytime</p>
            <p class="feature-text">
              Going on vacation? Just pause your subscription, and we refund
              unused days.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section-cta" id="cta">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="cta">
            <div class="cta-text-box">
              <h2 class="secondary-heading">Get your first meal for free!</h2>
              <p class="cta-text">
                Healthy, tasty and hassle-free meals are waiting for you. Start
                eating well today. You can cancel or pause anytime. And the
                first meal is on us!
              </p>
              <form class="cta-form" action="#">
                <div>
                  <label for="name"> Full name</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="John Smith"
                    id="name"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label for="email"> Email address</label>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="me@example.com"
                    id="email"
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label for="choose-form"> Where did you hear from us</label>
                  <select id="choose-form" required>
                    <option value="">Please choose one option:</option>
                    <option value="family">Friends and family</option>
                    <option value="youtube">Youtube video</option>
                    <option value="podcast">Podcast</option>
                    <option value="facebook">Facebook add</option>
                    <option value="others">Others</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn--form">Sign up now</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="cta-img-box"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container grid grid-footer">
        <div class="logo-col">
          <a class="footer-logo" href="#">
            <img class="logo" src="img/omnifood-logo.png" alt="omnifood logo" />
          </a>
          <div class="social-links">
            <a href="#"
              ><ion-icon class="footer-icon" name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon
            ></a>
            <a href="#"
              ><ion-icon class="footer-icon" name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon
            ></a>
            <a href="#"
              ><ion-icon class="footer-icon" name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon
            ></a>
          </div>
          <p class="copyright">
            Copyright &copy;<span class="year"> 2027</span> by Omnifood, Inc.
            All rights reserved.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-col">
          <p class="footer-heading">Contact us</p>
          <address class="contacts">
            <p class="address">
              623 Harrison St., 2nd Floor, San Francisco, CA 94107
            </p>
            <a class="footer-link" href="tel:415-201-6370"> 415-201-6370</a
            ><br />
            <a class="footer-link" href="mailto:hello@omnifood.com"
              >hello@omnifood.com</a
            >
          </address>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-col">
          <p class="footer-heading">Account</p>
          <ul class="footer-nav">
            <li>Create account</li>
            <li>Sign in</li>
            <li>iOS app</li>
            <li>Android app</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-col">
          <p class="footer-heading">Company</p>
          <ul class="footer-nav">
            <li>About Omnifood</li>
            <li>For Business</li>
            <li>Cooking partners</li>
            <li>Careers</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-col">
          <p class="footer-heading">Resources</p>
          <ul class="footer-nav">
            <li>Recipe directory</li>
            <li>Help center</li>
            <li>Privacy & terms</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule=""
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.